# No option to boot Ubuntu in a dual-boot machine

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, 12.10, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 next to Windows 7 in a separate NTFS partition.

I can boot Windows 7 but I can't find a way to choose Ubuntu and boot into it.

What do I do?

Comment: You say you installed Ubuntu in a NTFS partition. Did you use WUBI.EXE or did you boot boot from a live DVD/USB and install from there?

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 0):

You should consider installing Grub.

You can install it by using [Resc-A-Tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).
This little live disk is made to boot and install/restore grub.
It's very easy to use, you just boot it and select install/repair.